# How to increment a character in a QString (Qt)

Tags: c++, string, qt, qstring

I want to achieve the same effect as

```
 std::string s = "abc";
 s[1]++;
```

but with a `QString`, however Qt doesn't allow me to do this:

```
QString s = "abc";
s[1]++;
```

After which I get a compilation error.

Comment: Even if you don't understand the error message, somebody else probably would. Copy and paste it into the question.

Comment: `QString::operator[]` does not return a pointer. What do you expect to see?

Comment: binary '++' : 'QCharRef' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got around it by using:

```
text[i] = text[i].unicode() + 1;
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

`QString::operator[]` returns `QCharRef` which has no `operator++`.

You can get around this by doing something like:

```
s[1] = s[1].toAscii() + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `at()` method for`QString`

It works as below :

```
QString str = "abc";
QChar myChar = str.at(1) + 1
```

You can see `QString` operations in [this link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html)